# How to make the Eval function from Regex code ready for iMacros

Tags: regex, eval, imacros

I made this **Regex code** that is working perfect
https://regex101.com/r/ctMO3W/1

```js
const regex = /([A-Z a-z 0-9 ,;&!@#$%^&*()-`~=+ ]*)(?=">)/gu;

// Alternative syntax using RegExp constructor
// const regex = new RegExp('([A-Z a-z 0-9 ,;&!@#$%^&*()-`~=+ ]*)(?=">)', 'gu')

const str = `<meta name="description" content="TEst text, here is the text extracted">`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Basically my code extract a part of the text I need. The text between the " "  `content=".....">`

```
<meta name="description" content="here is the text extracted">
```

So far so good but..
I can't get it to work in iMacros with Eval function

I tried several option, don't know what to do anymore

```
SET newcontent EVAL("var s='{{content}}'; regex=/([A-Za-z0-9,;&!@#$%^&*()-`~=+ ]*)(?=">)/gu; s.replace(regex, '$&,');")
```

thank you for your help in this

**I am using (FCI):**
iMacros for CR v10.1.1 'PE', CR v105.0.5195.102 (_x64), Win10_x64.
('CR' = 'Chrome' / 'PE' = 'Personal Edition')

**LATER EDIT:**
Meanwhile I found a solution, work very well for me,  maybe will help others but still I want to understand what I do wrong on above question. Maybe someone can find a solution about that Regex code and how to implement it for iMacros.

```
SET newcontent EVAL("var u='{{content}}'; var x,y,z; x=u.split('content=\"'); y=x[1].split('\">'); z=y[0]; z;")
PROMPT {{newcontent}}
```

thanks again

Comment: Ah...!, OK, very good...!, you ***finally*** now have an FCI Section (iMacros Version still missing btw), (a bit lost in the middle of the Post btw, use a `CODE Block` and place it at the very Top of your Post, this is the very most important Info "Advanced" Users need), but mention it also in your 3 previous Threads for me to answer any of your (later) Threads/Qt's, sorry, I've mentioned it already 3 or 4 times after answering your very 1st one, I was "very nice" for the 1st one, but if you don't comply with my Quality-Reqs (for all Threads/Qt's), then I don't help again, sorry...

Comment: @chivracq Just edited all my previous posts. BTW, thank you so much that you take time and explain to me what I do wrong with FCI and others things, all your advices .. I want to serve the SO community  as community of SO helped me a lot.  I was just new but willing to learn. :) one more question. When I find the solution by my self, I write as an Answer or as a "Later Edit"? what option is good for community?

Comment: Regex bug alert! The character class includes `)-~` which is every character in the *range* `)` to `~` (inclusive), which is not what you intended. The fix is to either escape the `-` *or* place it last in the character class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> LATER EDIT: Meanwhile I found a solution [...]:
>
> ```scala
> SET newcontent EVAL("var u='{{content}}'; var x,y,z; x=u.split('content=\"'); y=x[1].split('\">'); z=y[0]; z;")
> PROMPT {{newcontent}}
> ```

Yep-yep, very good!, you managed to find one of my Posts (probably on the iMacros Forum 'Data Extraction' Sub-Forum where I've already posted this Solution dozens and dozens of times).
(And I know the Script/Sol is from me, I use a "pretty" specific Syntax, ah-ah...! :wink: )

---

Now answering this Qt (Question) like I had "planned" without/before seeing the "Later Edit" Section in the Qt... (=> with much more Info/Explanation... (=> not only for @OP, but for any other (future) User(s) with a similar Qt/Scenario)...)

=> OK, @OP, you have some `RegEx` Qt, you want some `RegEx` Solution, then hum, I "honestly" didn't even (*really*) read your Qt, just like you didn't *really* read the iMacros Tag [Wiki](/tags/imacros/info) (I wrote it myself...! (v1)) where I even "dedicated" a Section about `RegEx` <sub>nearly</sub> <sup>**NEVER**</sup> being the "Best" Sol/Implementation with iMacros, ah-ah...!

Then I would have 2 much-much-much easier Solutions for your Case/Scenario, without using `RegEx`...:

#### Sol 1:

> Basically my code extract a part of the text I need. The text between the " "  content=".....">
> `<meta name="description" content="here is the text extracted">`

=> Your "here is the text extracted" is enclosed between Double Quotes, => can use a simple/single `split()` to get your Data...:

```scala
SET Item EVAL("var s='{{!EXTRACT}}'; var z=s.split('\"'); z[3];")
PROMPT Extract:<SP>_{{!EXTRACT}}_<BR>Item:<SP>_{{Item}}_
```

"description" is also enclosed between Double Quotes, hence the `z[3]`, `split()`-Index starting at "0". (And `z[1]` would output this "description" String if you needed it...)

#### Sol 2:

Sol 1 is the "easiest" and simplest, but hum..., maybe not *always* completely reliable...:
For some "strange" Reasons (10(+) years Experience doing Data-Extraction with iMacros), Attributes of an HTML Element sometimes swap Order, so your `<meta name="description" content="here is the text extracted">` could upon a Refresh of the Page become `<meta content="here is the text extracted" name="description">`, and yep maybe not with only 2 Attr's, but that happens very often with more than 2 Attr's...
(I don't really have an Explanation why, maybe(?) the Order can be controlled/forced from the Server-Side, I don't think that's possible from the Client/Browser-Side..., or only using some 'UserScript' customized on ALL HTML Elements "important" for your iMacros Script..., and knowing "in Advance" all "unexpected" Situations that could happen, ... pretty cumbersome I would think..., and 'Sol 2' takes care of that, ah-ah...!)

This would/could also happen if you "played" with iMacros on that same Page without doing a "fresh" Refresh/Reload, as iMacros will inject some "pixel-line=blue" extra-Attr in the HTML Def of the Element, in any "random" Position, so there is no real "Assurance" that the `content` Attr will *always* be the 2nd Attr in the List, and therefore that `z[3]` will always be correct...!

=> More reliable would then be to be "more specific" on the 1st `split()` and to use the Name of the Attr as part of the `split()` like you already found out in your 'Later Edit' Section to your Qt, like in:

```scala
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
'Extracted: "<meta name="description" content="here is the text extracted">"
SET Item EVAL("var s='{{!EXTRACT}}', x,y,z; x=s.split('content=\"'); y=x[1].split('\"'); z=y[0]; z;")
PROMPT Extract:<SP>_{{!EXTRACT}}_<BR>Item:<SP>_{{Item}}_
```

`split()` is Case-Sensitive, make sure your "content" is not "Content" (with a Capital)...
And the `!ERRORIGNORE` (=YES) is needed in case the Extract is "empty" for any Reason (=> = "#EANF#"), or the `x[1]` will yield some Runtime Error, even inside the `EVAL()`...

And notice that I deliberately "only" used `y=x[1].split('\"');` for the 2nd `split()` (and not `y=x[1].split('\">');` like you used @OP), => not taking the `>` Char as that presumes that the "content" Attr will always be the last Attr in the HTML Extract, which might not always be true for the Reasons I explained.

---

<sub>Both Sols/Implementations not (specifically) tested for this specific Scenario/Thread/SO_Qt, no URL posted anyway...!, but tested many-many times "before" (in `v8.8.2 for FF` + `v8.9.7 for FF` + various Versions of PM ('Pale Moon') + FF ('Firefox')), ... and posted many times before on the iMacros Forum (where @OP probably found the Sol in the 'Later Edit' Section), this Answer and all Scripts written from scratch/memory, I could do some extra-Testing if "anything" is not correct, Typo or whatever...</sub>

Comment: I definitely found the solution on the forum, but I don't know exactly if it's from you, but I've seen that you've been very active everywhere for years. You bring a lot of value to iMacros users and we thank you :)

I find many of the solutions, but because I don't speak English natively, sometimes I search with a translation from my language, sometimes I find the solutions or something similar, sometimes not.

Comment: Alright, Thanks for the 'Accept'... I added a Remark/mini-Section about your `y=x[1].split('\">');` which might fail in some Cases because of the `>` Char, for the same Reasons Sol 1 might not always be completely reliable, so  you may want to read my Edit...